Filtering incorrect letters in React app not working properly
I'm writing a simple Hangman game using React and trying to implement functionality to filter out incorrectly guessed letters from the word. The Keyboard (buttons) and HangmanDrawing components seem to be working fine, as the console always logs the letters clicked.
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import HangmanDrawing from "./components/HangmanDrawing";
import Keyboard from "./components/Keyboard";
import WordToGuess from "./components/WordToGuess";

const options = {

};

export default function App() {
    const [word, setWord] = useState<string | null>(null);
    const [guessedLetters, setGuessedLetters] = useState<string[]>([]);
    **const incorrectLetters: string[] = guessedLetters.filter(
        (letter) => !word?.includes(letter)
    );**

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchWord = async () => {
            try {
                const response = await axios.request(options);
                setWord(response.data);
            } catch (error) {
                console.error(error);
            }
        };

        fetchWord();
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(word);
        console.log(guessedLetters);
        console.log(incorrectLetters);
    }, [guessedLetters]);

    return (
        <div>
            <HangmanDrawing incorrect={incorrectLetters.length} />
            {word && (
                <WordToGuess
                    word={word}
                    guessedLetters={guessedLetters}
                />
            )}
            <Keyboard
                guessedLetters={guessedLetters}
                setGuessedLetters={setGuessedLetters}
            />
        </div>
    );
}


The console logs:
hippodrome
(11) ['G', 'H', 'D', 'J', 'L', 'K', 'I', 'E', 'F', 'C', 'O'] // incorrect array
(11) ['G', 'H', 'D', 'J', 'L', 'K', 'I', 'E', 'F', 'C', 'O'] // incorrect array
[] // correct array

Code for other components: https://pastebin.com/cQx1X99R

What do you expect the console logs to show instead? Also, where are those logs coming from? I assume the first 3 are from your useEffect(), but where's the last one coming from? It might also be good if you share how you're using setGuessedLetters in KeyBoard.

Try adding toUpperCase onto word :
const incorrectLetters: string[] = guessedLetters.filter(
        (letter) => !word?.toUpperCase().includes(letter)
    );

As your word is all lowercase and the includes is case sensitive.
Also should correct array value for incorrect letters  be '["G", "J", "L", "K", "F", "C"]' as these are the ones guessed that dont appear in the word?
